# auto call AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this code, I have 2 AsyncTask I called that by button, and I have one more I want to ask is there any way to call the Asynctask automatic when is open the activity?

I tried to but it with onCreate but it is error

```
public class SingleCompleteOrder extends ActionBarActivity {


    private static final String comp_id = "complete_id";
    private static final String comp_table = "complete_table";
    private static final String comp_items = "complete_items";
    private static final String comp_date = "complete_date";

    private TextView oid;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {


            case android.R.id.home:

                onBackPressed();

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_contact);    




        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

public void huss() {
            Updatsituation task = new Updatsituation ();
            task.execute();


}
private class Updatsituation extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>  {
        private ProgressDialog pd;
        private Boolean result = false;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(SingleCompleteOrder.this);
            pd.setMessage("Processing commend,Please wait");
            pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Utils.WS_UPDATE_SITUAT);

            List<NameValuePair> mParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("complete_id", oid.getText().toString()));
            mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("order_situation","showed"));

            try {

                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(mParams));

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                Log.d("Order Preview", res);

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(res);

                result = jsonObj.getBoolean("Result");


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean res) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(res);

            if (pd != null)
                pd.dismiss();

            if (res) {

                Toast.makeText(SingleCompleteOrder.this,
                        "Order Completed Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                finish();

                Intent intent = new Intent(SingleCompleteOrder.this,
                        CompleteOrdertest.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(SingleCompleteOrder.this,
                        "Unable to process the command", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the Async task for when the Activity is created you can do this in your `OnCreate` method. or if you want to execute this every time the Activity come to visibility, you can run this in `onResume` method.

I do not see you are calling your huss() method in any of your `OnCreate` or `OnResume` methods.

EDIT: Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_contact);    
        huss();



        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your AsyncTask, simply do the following within your onCreate() method of the Activity:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // All lines of code
    new Updatsituation().execute(); 
}
```

This should fire up the task without you having to click any button.

You can put it inside onResume() but then be prepared to have it start everytime your activity resumes.

Comment: yes thank's, I tried this thing it is be unfortunately

Comment: also, I checked the same class with button it is worked but i need it auto

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call AsyncTask automatically, then you need to call it on OnCreate() method.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new Updatsituation().execute(); //call your async task

}
```

Comment: yes thank's, I tried this thing it is be unfortunately

Comment: post your log @HussainAali